# Weyl transform of a product of operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am struggling with a demonstration about Weyl transform properties. In particular, I want to prove
$$\tilde{(\hat{A}\hat{B})}(x, p) = \tilde{A}(x,p)\exp(i\Lambda/2\hbar)\tilde{B}(x,p)\,,$$
where $\Lambda$ is the Poisson bracket operator. I will show some passages:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\tilde{(\hat{A}\hat{B})}(x, p) & = \int e^{-ipy/\hbar} \langle x+y/2| \hat{A}\hat{B}|x-y/2\rangle dy \\
& = \int e^{-ipy/\hbar} \langle x+y/2| \hat{A}|z\rangle \langle z|\hat{B}|x-y/2\rangle dy dz \,.
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

I have also derived the expression
$$\langle x|\hat{A}|x^{\prime}\rangle = \int dp e^{ip(x-x^\prime)/\hbar} \tilde{A}((1/2)(x-x^\prime), p)\,.$$
Also, substituing it in the previous equation I cannot see where the Poisson bracket operator shows up.

Comment: Standard PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/467239/wigner-map-of-the-product-of-two-operators), not to mention [Groenewold's original one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391361/groenewold-derivation-of-moyal-bracket-on-the-principles-of-elementary-quantum). Try a decent [text](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf).

Comment: Hint:  use Lagrange's shift operator, $A(x+y)= e^{y \partial_x}  ~f(x)$, repeatedly and judiciously.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help!